# How to center vertically and hor an h1 on a page?

Tags: html, css

I currently do:

html:

```
 <div id="narrate">
    <h1>Imagine everything.</h1>
    <span class="preloading">
        <i class="icon-spinner icon-spin icon-2x"></i>
    </span>
</div>
```

Css

```
#narrate {
    margin:0 ;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: -200px;
    height: 20px;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: 700;
}

.preloading {
    height: 20px;
    visibility: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
```

I would like both the h1 and the spinner icon to be centered on the page, the spinner icon be below the h1.

The above code isn't really centering, there is some pixelout position.

I have tried:

```
#narrate {
    margin:0 ;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
    margin-top: -150px;
    margin-left: -250px;
    height: 20px;
}
```

Comment: you want #narrate to be in center?

Comment: yes.. #narrate is just a container div for both the h1 and the spinner icon really, I am fading those on load. And what I am trying to do is to have them both centered on the page and have the icon below the h1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `display:table-cell`

```
#narrate {
    margin:0 ;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
      display:table-cell;
    vertical-align:middle; background:grey;
    height: 300px;
    width: 500px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/X9LfB/1/)**

---

Try this

```
html, body{
    height:100%;
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
#narrate {
     background:grey;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
   position:relative;
    vertical-align:middle; 
   display:table;
}

h1 {
    font-size: 3em;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif !important;
    font-weight: 700; display:table-cell; 
    vertical-align:middle; 
    text-align:center;
}
span{
    display:block;
    font-size:12px
}
```

**[DEMO 2](http://jsfiddle.net/X9LfB/7/)**

Comment: yeah but that puts the #narrate div top left of the page. Isn't what I was asking

Comment: it'd be what I'm looking for if heigth and width would be 100% in your example but that doens't work

Comment: finally code that works for what should be a simple solution (when it's actually not), thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your are looking for the positioning the div centered hor and vert then, use margin:auto

```
#narrate {
    width: 380px;
    height: 280px;
    margin: 70px auto;
    background: #ccc;
    text-align: center;
}
```

**DEMO**
http://jsfiddle.net/X9LfB/6/

**EDIT:**

Vertical center would require you to constrain your body say 500px and then set margin-top to center it vertically.

Comment: should be adding line-height: 280px to the h1.. but still #narrate isn't exactly centered vertically on the page, not even in your jsfiddle

Comment: give the body a height of say 500 px and accordingly center it with margin-top which is 70 now.